# Compiler closes automatically when displaying output

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I want to input values and then display the values that I input but after I input the values, it displays the output a half second before closing automatically.

Here is my code

```
    #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float startnummer;
    float hoppnummer;
    float svarighetsgrad;
    float domarpoang1;
    float domarpoang2;
    float domarpoang3;
    float domarpoang4;
    float domarpoang5;
    float domarpoang6;
    float domarpoang7;

    printf("Startnummer: \n");
    scanf_s("%f", &startnummer );

    printf("Hoppnummer:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &hoppnummer);

    printf("Svarighetsgrad:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &svarighetsgrad);

    printf("Domarpoang 1:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &domarpoang1);

    printf("Domarpoang 2:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &domarpoang2);

    printf("Domarpoang 3:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &domarpoang3);

    printf("Domarpoang 4:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &domarpoang4);

    printf("Domarpoang 5:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &domarpoang5);

    printf("Domarpoang 6:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &domarpoang6);

    printf("Domarpoang 7:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &domarpoang7);

    printf("Startnummer: %f \n", startnummer);
    printf("Hoppnummer:\n", hoppnummer);
    printf("Svarighetsgrad:\n", svarighetsgrad);
    printf("Domarpoang 1:\n", domarpoang1);
    printf("Domarpoang 2:\n", domarpoang2);
    printf("Domarpoang 3:\n", domarpoang3);
    printf("Domarpoang 4:\n", domarpoang4);
    printf("Domarpoang 5:\n", domarpoang5);
    printf("Domarpoang 6:\n", domarpoang6);
    printf("Domarpoang 7:\n", domarpoang7);

    printf("Hoppoang: \n");

    printf("Tryck tangent for nytt hopp!");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know how to make it so it doesn't close automatically when displaying the output?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

getchar() won't work if there are any characters buffered in ***stdin***. 
If you are using Visual Studio then execute the program by pressing **Ctrl + F5**. This will keep the window open and wait for key press to exit.